# Custom error message for phonegap in android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using phonegap for my android app. My app loads a webpage from remote server. Now i need to generate a custom error message if the connection was unsuccesful.

Phonegap already contains a default error alert using an Alertbox

> Application Error
>
> > The connection to the sever was unsuccessful. (http://yoursite.com)

Can i customize this error message?

Answer (score 0):

use this `

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialoglayout);

                TextView dialogbody=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogbody);

                Button dialogok=(Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogok);

                dialogok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();   


                    }
                });

                dialogbody.setText(displayText);
                dialog.show();`
```